# How can I handle Ineheritence for my data model Structs to have a Main Struct with different sub structs that represent different types?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have various types of Worksheet structs that I use to populate a view, where the user fills out entries and these are then saved.

So far I've just used each struct individually, but I realized it would be more efficient to have a main 'Worksheet' struct that holds the common properties (id, date) so that I can reuse some views rather than creating a different view for every single type of Worksheet.

For example, here is how I read data of a certain worksheet:

```
  if let diaryArray = vm.readData(of: [Diary](), from: "diary_data") {
                let sortedArray = diaryArray.sorted(by: {$0.date > $1.date})
                vm.diaries = sortedArray
            }
```

I'd like this to be something like

```
 if let diaryArray = vm.readData(of: [T](), from: "\(path)_data") {
                let sortedArray = diaryArray.sorted(by: {$0.date > $1.date})
                vm.worksheets = sortedArray
            }
```

So, I won't know what type of worksheet it is yet, but that it is a worksheet that has a date property for sure, so I can sort it by that, with this approach I could just reuse this view and function instead of having to write this for every type.

I've tried two ways so far to achieve this with my structs:

firstly, using protocols:

```
protocol Worksheet: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
  var id: String { get set }
  var date: Date { get set }
}

extension Worksheet {
static func parseVehicleFields(id: String, date: Date) -> (String, Date) {
    let id = ""
    let date = Date()
    return (id, date)
}
}

struct Diary: Worksheet {

var id: String
var date: Date


var title: String
var situation: String
var thoughts: String
var emotions: String
var physicalSensations: String
var behaviours: String
var analysis: String
var alternative: String
var outcome: String

init() {
    
    self.id = ""
    self.date = Date()

    self.title = ""
    self.situation = ""
    self.thoughts = ""
    self.emotions = ""
    self.physicalSensations = ""
    self.behaviours = ""
    self.analysis = ""
    self.alternative = ""
    self.outcome = ""
}

}

struct Goal: Worksheet {

var mainGoal: String

var notificationActive: Bool
var notificationDate: Date

var obstacles: String
var positiveBehaviours: String

var immediateActions: String

var goalAchieved: Bool

init() {

    self.mainGoal = ""
    self.notificationActive = false
    self.notificationDate = Date()
    
    self.obstacles = ""
    self.positiveBehaviours = ""
    
    self.immediateActions = ""
    self.goalAchieved = false
}

}
```

It seems close, but I get the error of 'Type 'any Worksheet' cannot conform to 'Decodable''

when trying this:

```
            if let array = vm.readData(of: [any Worksheet](), from: "\(path)_data") {
                let sortedArray = array.sorted(by: {$0.date > $1.date})
                vm.worksheets = sortedArray
            }
```

Here is the save function for reference:

```
func saveWorksheetProtocol<T: Worksheet>(for type: [T], to path: String) {
        let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first
        let documentURL = (directoryURL?.appendingPathComponent(path).appendingPathExtension("json"))!
        let jsonEncoder = JSONEncoder()
        let data = try? jsonEncoder.encode(type)
        do {
            try data?.write(to: documentURL, options: .noFileProtection)
        } catch {
            print("Error...Cannot save data!!!See error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

It works if I use Diary as the parameter, but that defeats the point of trying to make this Generic to Worksheets, not their specific types.

Alternatively, I tried a method that creates a major Struct type of Worksheet, that contains the other types. This actually works nicely, except I have to hold empty data for EVERY type of worksheet, if I want to create an array of only 'Diary' entries for example, and this seems redundant and inefficient:

```
struct Worksheet: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {

  var id: String
  var date: Date
  var diary: Diary2
  var goal: Goal2
  var experiment: Experiment2

init() {

    self.id = ""
    self.date = Date()
    self.diary = Diary2()
    self.goal = Goal2()
    self.experiment = Experiment2()

}

}

struct Diary: Codable, Hashable {

var title: String
var situation: String
var thoughts: String
var emotions: String
var physicalSensations: String
var behaviours: String
var analysis: String
var alternative: String
var outcome: String

init() {

    self.title = ""
    self.situation = ""
    self.thoughts = ""
    self.emotions = ""
    self.physicalSensations = ""
    self.behaviours = ""
    self.analysis = ""
    self.alternative = ""
    self.outcome = ""
}

}

struct Goal: Codable, Hashable {

var mainGoal: String

var notificationActive: Bool
var notificationDate: Date

var obstacles: String
var positiveBehaviours: String

var immediateActions: String

var goalAchieved: Bool

init() {

    self.mainGoal = ""
    self.notificationActive = false
    self.notificationDate = Date()
    
    self.obstacles = ""
    self.positiveBehaviours = ""
    
    self.immediateActions = ""
    self.goalAchieved = false
}

}
```

So here I can just find a specific 'Worksheet', sort it, and then later access the values of whichever one it is, i.e. worksheet.diary.title, worksheet.goal.title etc. But this means each entry has redundant values of every other, and I tried making each type optional, but I could not then use them with bindings, as I was getting unresolvable unwrap errors, if the type i.e. 'Diary?' was optional in the Worksheet struct:

```
                    TextField("", text: $entry.diary!.title, axis: .vertical) <- error would be here, even when checking if diary exist first.
                        .lineLimit(20)
                        .disabled(!editMode)
```

So I am looking for a way to handle my Worksheet types more efficiently, so that I can reduce repetitive code for functions and views where possible.

Comment: But you are still going to have a problem using a JSON file as your persistence system. JSON doesn't tell you what *type* of object is encoded. You will need to use custom decoding to look at an outer `type` property of your json and then decode the appropriate subtype

Comment: I think the answer to this is don't bother

Comment: @malhal that is what I've been stuck deciding to do, it seems like it's possible but then becomes a big hassle, and the whole point is I want to reduce some of the code I need and make it cleaner. The second solution technically works but it just seems so bloated to carry empty values for every type of diary, when I only need 1. I guess I'll probably just keep them seperate and continue making seperate views and functions for each type for now. Unless there is something I'm missing or a better way to do it.